# How to change move cursor location when in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, transforms, 3d-cursor

So I want to move 2 vetext at the same time but i want to use snap mode and move them based on the location of one of the vertex. How do I change the move cursor?[image]

So this for example. What if i want to move it in abolute grid to make sure it matches but i want to make sure the move cursor is on the corner that is on the gird.
[image]
Is there a way to do that?
(This questions also works if i want to move an edge or a face in absolute gird snap mode based on a specific vertex)

Answer (score -1):

NVM I FINALLY FOUND A GOOD VIDOE ON IT
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=clcyYUM29bQ
here is the link i am so happy to have found this
Dont know if there is a way to make the cursor follow the edge or vertex you made as the pivot point when you move it